# "symtdi.sys" Is Causing Blue-screen After Upgrading To Norton Internet Security 2012?

Tags: windows-vista, bsod, norton-internet-security

I've just updated a Windows Vista machine to Service Pack 1. Subsequently, I upgraded the previously disabled Norton Internet Security 7 (expired) to Norton Internet Security 2012.

On reboot I get a consistent blue-screen, caused by `SYMTDI.SYS` that says, `DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS`. How can I clear this up?

Comment: See http://www.pchelpforum.com/windows-vista-7/130066-bluescreen-symtdi-sys-stop-0x000000ce-please-help.html and http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/blue-sceen-symtdisys-visat-32-bit-after-upgrading-12x-client for similar issues

Comment: You could/should have run the Norton Removal Tool - it often clears up errors caused by uninstalling Norton programs. Upgrading with a large version difference is essentially uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: You really should install Service Pack 2 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `SYMTDI.SYS` in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` by booting up in the restore mode, going to advanced system recovery options, and launching a command prompt. I renamed it to `SYMTDI.BAK` and rebooted successfully

Comment: So, this may disable some functionality, but at least the system boots and seems to function OK

Comment: The file in question is Symantec’s device driver.  There is an exploit in versions from 2005-2006 in a report I found from 2007.  http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/security/Content/2007.07.11d.html  You really should be using Visa Service Pack 2.  Be sure you clean the previous installation out before trying install the new version of Norton/Symantec

Answer (score 0):

http://file.net/process/symtdi.sys.html   apparently it crashes things on XP a lot, only one or two reports from vista.  many people argue that its a part of Symantec or Norton.  One guy says it crashes every dell he's tried it with.  And they say malware sometimes uses the name.  You can scan it at: https://www.virustotal.com/ assuming you can find and copy it.  Bottom line seems to be (based on file.net reports) that switching to a different antivirus (Microsoft Security essentials Avast, AVG and ClamWin are some free options).  If you can boot up in safe mode and uninstall Norton.?